# I believe I need to take a certain kind of product of sets or compute permutations / combinations, but I'm not sure which...

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, products

Consider the following definitions...

```
a = (c, d)
b = (e, f)

c = (g, h)
d = (i, j)

e = (k, l)
f = (m, n)
```

I need to compute some kind of product / permutations / combinations, such that I get the following set of tuples. The idea is to compute all possible paths through the dependencies. What should I use here, and how do these types of things generalize, ie I imagine permutations / combinations are types of products so is there a good way to help construct new products that maybe be required?

```
(a, c, g)
(a, c, h)
(a, d, i)
(a, d, j)
(b, e, k)
(b, e, l)
(b, f, m)
(b, f, n)
```

Comment: I don't understand how the triplets are supposed to arise.

Comment: @Randall one triplet would come from selecting a, which would give two options, c and d, then selecting one of these would give another two options and so on, there should be 3 options until there are no more dependencies, hence we can only make 3 choices.

Comment: Am I right to conclude that since $b=(e,f)$ and $f=(m,n)$, then $b=(e,(m,n))$? Or should you be more careful with your symbols?

Comment: @BernardMassé that does make sense but we would lose the reference this way I believe. The problem is the same as finding all paths to leaves in a tree, I'm wondering if there is a concise math way to say this, or do I need to use an algorithm?